Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute in Jasmine and karma tests with angular
I'm having this message in 20 of my tests that worked perfectly before:
Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

All test are failing with angular, jasmine and karma.
What I did before running the tests again was changing one function to another:
Old function:
    public isDisabledDQReviewer(): boolean {
        const periodicity = this.typeSettingForm.get('periodicity').value;
        const isDaily = periodicity === 'Diaria';
        const isDisabled = !this.isRoleGMRU || isDaily;


        if (isDaily) {
            this.typeSettingForm.get('reviewer').setValue(false);
        }


        return isDisabled;
    }


New function:
    public checkDQReviewerStatus(): void {
        const periodicity = this.typeSettingForm.get('periodicity').value;
        const isDaily = periodicity === 'Diaria';
        const isMonthly = periodicity === 'Mensual';

        const isDisabled = !this.isRoleGMRU || isDaily;

        if (isDaily) {
            this.typeSettingForm.get('reviewer').setValue(false);
        }

        if (isDisabled) {
            this.typeSettingForm.get('reviewer').disable({ emitEvent: false });
        } else {
            this.typeSettingForm.get('reviewer').enable({ emitEvent: false });
        }
        if (isMonthly && this.isRoleGMRU) {
            this.typeSettingForm.get('reviewer').enable();
        }
    }

All testing according to this component are failing, even though they don't include this function. These are some examples:
    it('is defined', () => {
        expect(testing.component).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should disable reviewer if role is not GMRU', () => {
        testing.component.typeSettingForm.get('periodicity').setValue('Diaria');


        const result = testing.component.checkDQReviewerStatus();


        expect(result).toBeTruthy();
        expect(testing.component.typeSettingForm.get('reviewer').value).toBe(false);
    });

I changed the name of the function in every test and I try to redo them, but nothing seems to work.
I need those tests to run correctly.
